# URP PostProcessing doesn't work?

Tags: unity, post-processing

[image]

I'm trying to get postprocessing work again after updated to URP. But it does not work !!

Could anyone help me with any solution or clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Main Camera component put the tick in Rendering > Post Processing. You also don't need to have a separate layer for the volume and camera any longer as far as I know. Should not make a difference for whether it's working or not, though.

If you're working with volume triggers do not forget to put a collider on the object.

Comment: Thank you so much.